# Unable to invoke method declare in class implement generic interface method

Tags: delphi, generics

Delphi support generic for `IInterface`.  I have the follow construct using generic `IInterface`:

```
type
  IVisitor<T> = interface
  ['{9C353AD4-6A3A-44FD-B924-39B86A4CB14D}']
    procedure Visit(o: T);
  end;

  TMyVisitor = class(TInterfacedObject, IVisitor<TButton>, IVisitor<TEdit>)
    procedure Visit(o: TButton); overload;
    procedure Visit(o: TEdit); overload;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyVisitor.Visit(o: TButton);
begin
  ShowMessage('Expected: TButton, Actual: ' + o.ClassName);
end;

procedure TMyVisitor.Visit(o: TEdit);
begin
  ShowMessage('Expected: TEdit, Actual: ' + o.ClassName);
end;
```

`TMyVisitor` class implement two interface: `IVisitor<TButton>` and `IVisitor<TEdit>`.

I attempt invoke the methods:

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var V: IInterface;
begin
  V := TMyVisitor.Create;
  (V as IVisitor<TButton>).Visit(Button1);
  (V as IVisitor<TEdit>).Visit(Edit1);
end;
```

The output I have is:

```
Expected: TEdit, Actual: TButton
Expected: TEdit, Actual: TEdit
```

Apparently, the code doesn't invoke `procedure TMyVisitor.Visit(o: TButton)` when execute `(V as IVisitor<TButton>).Visit(Button1)`.

Is this a bug in Delphi or I should avoid implement multiple generic `IInterface`?   All above codes have test in `Delphi XE6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as` operator requires interface GUID to be able to tell which interface you are referring to. Since generic interfaces share same GUID `as` operator will not work with them. Basically, compiler cannot tell the difference between IVisitor<TButton> and IVisitor<TEdit> interfaces.

However, you can solve your problem using enhanced RTTI:

```
type
  TCustomVisitor = class(TObject)
  public
    procedure Visit(Instance: TObject); 
  end;

  TVisitor = class(TCustomVisitor)
  public
    procedure VisitButton(Instance: TButton); overload;
    procedure VisitEdit(Instance: TEdit); overload;
  end;

procedure TCustomVisitor.Visit(Instance: TObject);
var
  Context: TRttiContext;
  CurrentClass: TClass;
  Params: TArray<TRttiParameter>;
  ParamType: TRttiType;
  SelfMethod: TRttiMethod;
  s: string;
begin
  Context := TRttiContext.Create;
  CurrentClass := Instance.ClassType;
  repeat
    s := CurrentClass.ClassName;
    Delete(s, 1, 1); // remove "T"
    for SelfMethod in Context.GetType(Self.ClassType).GetMethods('Visit' + s) do
      begin
        Params := SelfMethod.GetParameters;
        if (Length(Params) = 1) then
          begin
            ParamType := Params[0].ParamType;
            if ParamType.IsInstance and (ParamType.AsInstance.MetaclassType = CurrentClass) then
              begin
                SelfMethod.Invoke(Self, [Instance]);
                Exit;
              end;
          end;
      end;
    CurrentClass := CurrentClass.ClassParent;
  until CurrentClass = nil;
end;
```

If you need to have Visitor interface you can change declarations to

```
type
  IVisitor = interface
  ['{9C353AD4-6A3A-44FD-B924-39B86A4CB14D}']
    procedure Visit(Instance: TObject);
  end;

  TCustomVisitor = class(TInterfacedObject, IVisitor)
  public
    procedure Visit(Instance: TObject); 
  end;
```

You can then use that in following manner, just by calling Visit and appropriate Visit method will be called.

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var V: IVisitor;
begin
  V := TMyVisitor.Create;
  V.Visit(Button1);
  V.Visit(Edit1);
end;
```

Above code is based on Uwe Raabe's code and you can read more http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/?s=visitor

And here is extended visitor interface and class that can operate on non-class types. I have implemented only calls for string, but implementation for other types consists only of copy-paste code with different typecast.

```
  IVisitor = interface
  ['{9C353AD4-6A3A-44FD-B924-39B86A4CB14D}']
    procedure Visit(const Instance; InstanceType: PTypeInfo);
    procedure VisitObject(Instance: TObject);
  end;

  TCustomVisitor = class(TInterfacedObject, IVisitor)
  public
    procedure Visit(const Instance; InstanceType: PTypeInfo);
    procedure VisitObject(Instance: TObject);
  end;

procedure TCustomVisitor.Visit(const Instance; InstanceType: PTypeInfo);
var
  Context: TRttiContext;
  Params: TArray<TRttiParameter>;
  ParamType: TRttiType;
  SelfMethod: TRttiMethod;
begin
  Context := TRttiContext.Create;
  case InstanceType.Kind of
    tkClass : VisitObject(TObject(Instance));
    // template how to implement calls for non-class types
    tkUString :
      begin
        for SelfMethod in Context.GetType(Self.ClassType).GetMethods('VisitString') do
          begin
            Params := SelfMethod.GetParameters;
            if (Length(Params) = 1) then
              begin
                ParamType := Params[0].ParamType;
                if ParamType.TypeKind = tkUString then
                  begin
                    SelfMethod.Invoke(Self, [string(Instance)]);
                    Exit;
                  end;
              end;
          end;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomVisitor.VisitObject(Instance: TObject);
var
  Context: TRttiContext;
  CurrentClass: TClass;
  Params: TArray<TRttiParameter>;
  ParamType: TRttiType;
  SelfMethod: TRttiMethod;
  s: string;
begin
  Context := TRttiContext.Create;
  CurrentClass := Instance.ClassType;
  repeat
    s := CurrentClass.ClassName;
    Delete(s, 1, 1); // remove "T"
    for SelfMethod in Context.GetType(Self.ClassType).GetMethods('Visit' + s) do
      begin
        Params := SelfMethod.GetParameters;
        if (Length(Params) = 1) then
          begin
            ParamType := Params[0].ParamType;
            if ParamType.IsInstance and (ParamType.AsInstance.MetaclassType = CurrentClass) then
              begin
                SelfMethod.Invoke(Self, [Instance]);
                Exit;
              end;
          end;
      end;
    CurrentClass := CurrentClass.ClassParent;
  until CurrentClass = nil;
end;
```

Enhanced Visitor can be used like this:

```
  TVisitor = class(TCustomVisitor)
  public
    procedure VisitButton(Instance: TButton); overload;
    procedure VisitEdit(Instance: TEdit); overload;
    procedure VisitString(Instance: string); overload;
  end;


var
  v: IVisitor;
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'this is string';
  v := TVisitor.Create;

  // class instances can be visited directly via VisitObject
  v.VisitObject(Button1); 

  v.Visit(Edit1, TypeInfo(TEdit));
  v.Visit(s, TypeInfo(string));
end;
```

Comment: The element in visitor may not be TObject descendant.  It could be `string`, `Integer`, record type or other non-class element.  Using `RTTI` complicate the coding.

Comment: I have added enhanced visitor class and interface that can operate on any type you need.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known problem with generic interfaces. Here is yours:

```
type
  IVisitor<T> = interface
    ['{9C353AD4-6A3A-44FD-B924-39B86A4CB14D}']
    procedure Visit(o: T);
  end;
```

Now, the `as` operator is implemented on top of the GUID that you specify for the interface. When you write:

```
(V as IVisitor<TButton>).Visit(Button1);
(V as IVisitor<TEdit>).Visit(Edit1);
```

how can the `as` operator distinguish between `IVisitor<TButton>` and `IVisitor<TEdit>`? You have only specified a single GUID. In fact when this happens, all instantiated types based on this generic interface share the same GUID. And so whilst the `as` operator compiles, and the code executes, the runtime behaviour is ill-defined. In effect you are defining multiple interfaces and giving them all the same GUID.

So, the fundamental issue here is that the `as` operator is not compatible with generic interfaces. You will have to find some other way to implement this. You might consider looking at the Spring4D project for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Can you point out which part in `Spring4D` that may inspire me?

Comment: The part that implemented the visitor pattern is what I'm thinking of

Comment: I grep the Spring4D source but couldn't find visitor pattern implementation.

Comment: You are right. They have Observer but not Visitor it seems. Anyway, I'm not sure I'm in a position to advise you what to do. Not least because I don't know your goals. I just tried to answer the question that you asked.

Comment: You point out the usage of `as` and generic interface is a known problem in Delphi.  I think there is no alternative solution for the problem I face so far.

Comment: Well, you cannot solves your problem with `as` and that generic interface. But I'm quite sure there is an alternative way to implement something that solves your problem, whatever it is.